# QGIS - Map won't allow me to move around, only shows bottom half of Africa

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

[image]

I just installed QGIS today, so I'm very new to it. I've installed the Quick Map Services plugin and tried adding Google Maps, Google Satellite, Bing Maps, etc., and none of them seem to let me pan beyond this section shown here.

It's the bottom half of Africa. Whenever I try to pan somewhere else, it shows blank map around this section and snaps back to here.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: On your screenshot you have another layer, do you have the same problem without it ? (to check start a new QGIS and only add one of the Quick Map Services basemap) if removing the DEM solve the problem you probably have a projection issue on your DEM

Comment: You're right, that was it. I started a new map and added just a base layer and it works now. Thanks!